# subprocess failure - Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am attempting to convert a `.dot` file (an output of a visualization of a decision tree) to a `.jpg` file. Code is below:

```
estimator = rf.estimators_[5]

export_graphviz(estimator, 
                out_file='C:\\Users\\Jerry\\Desktop\\tree.dot', 
                feature_names = ['count_bot', 'count_human', '%_bot_tweets',  'following',  'followers'],
                class_names = ['bot', 'human'],
                rounded = True, proportion = False, 
                precision = 2, filled = True)
call(['dot', '-Tpng', 'C:\\Users\\Jerry\\Desktop\\tree.dot', '-o', 'C:\\Users\\Jerry\\Desktop\\tree.png', '-Gdpi=600'])
```

It yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filepath\Bot_or_Not.py", line 89, in <module>
    call(['dot', '-Tpng', 'C:\\Users\\Jerry\\Desktop\\tree.dot', '-o', 'C:\\Users\\Jerry\\Desktop\\tree.png', '-Gdpi=600'])
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 304, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1155, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

[I am trying to follow this tutorial.](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-visualize-a-decision-tree-from-a-random-forest-in-python-using-scikit-learn-38ad2d75f21c)

What is wrong with my line: `call(['dot', '-Tpng', 'C:\\Users\\Jerry\\Desktop\\tree.dot', '-o', 'C:\\Users\\Jerry\\Desktop\\tree.png', '-Gdpi=600'])`

By the way, I can confirm `tree.dot` is on my desktop

**Response to comments:**

The command I am running is:
`python Bot_or_Not.py`

The rest of the script (actually building / training / testing the classifier) runs just fine.

`python --version` yields:

`Python 3.7.0`

`python -m pip install Graphviz` yields:

`C:\Users\Jerry>python -m pip install Graphviz
Requirement already satisfied: Graphviz in c:\users\Jerry\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (0.13.2)`

Comment: Is the location of "dot.exe" in the PATH?

Comment: Sorry. I do not know what `dot.exe` is. I did just check my PATH and that was not in there.

Comment: Python can't run a program that isn't installed. If you haven't installed Graphviz (the program it comes with), you can't expect to have `dot`.

Comment: You try to call "dot.exe" (part of GraphViz suite) to process "tree.dot" to create "tree.png".

Comment: First of all ...your cmd work?...can you share us how is your command?

Comment: I do have `Graphviz` installed. I didn't know `dot.exe` was an executable in that package.

Comment: Edited post to answer these questions.

Comment: ...so, does your PATH include the location where Graphviz put its executables?

Comment: Also, the question was not if you have the Graphviz Python module installed, but the native Graphviz application (which cannot be installed with pip, but is instead installed as a regular Windows application); they're two different things, and the former will not work without the latter.

Comment: I don't quite think the issue is with Graphviz, since I have the `.dot` file on my desktop which I can paste into `http://viz-js.com/` and get the visual to work just fine. I am trying to do this via the `call` which is where my error is.

Comment: Graphviz was also installed via `.msi` file from https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/

Comment: Good. Next question (and repeating myself): is the location where the MSI installed its executables listed in your PATH? (That's not a Python-ism; the PATH is also how cmd.exe finds programs to run, for example).

Comment: A desktop shortcut (with an absolute path embedded, so there's no need for a PATH lookup at runtime) tells us nothing about whether your environment variable setup is correct; so it doesn't prove anything useful. More valuable would be to check if you can run dot from `cmd.exe`, which also requires a correct PATH.

Comment: Yes, it is. the `msi` installed the files in `C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib` which is in `PATH` (along with many others).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203143/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-jerry-m).